# How do I determine what line is throwing a Null exception error in Server Side Blazor UI

Tags: blazor-server-side, nullreferenceexception

Here is my UI
The error is thrown somewhere in this code snippet when the "Add Item" button is pressed, but I cannot pinpoint what or where the NullException error is being thrown. is there any way to isolate this?

```
 <TelerikGrid Data="@_claim.Items.ToList()" TItem="BQM.Data.Models.Claim_Item"
                    EditMode="Telerik.Blazor.GridEditMode.Inline" Width="100%" Pageable="true"
                    OnRowContextMenu="@OnRowContextMenuHandler"
                    OnUpdate="@UpdateItem" OnDelete="@DeleteItem" OnCreate="@CreateItem" OnEdit="@EditItem">
          <GridToolBar>
             <AuthorizeView Policy="@Policies.ClaimRebateItemCreateEdit" Context="Edit">
                <AddButton linkText="Add Item" />
             </AuthorizeView>
             <span class="k-toolbar-spacer"></span>
             <GridSearchBox DebounceDelay="200"></GridSearchBox>
          </GridToolBar>
          <GridColumns>
             <GridColumn Field=@nameof(BQM.Data.Models.Claim_Item.BidId)>
                <EditorTemplate>
                   @{
                      var _claimItem = context as Data.Models.Claim_Item;
                      <TelerikComboBox @bind-Value="@_claimItem.BidId" Data="@_bids"
                                       TextField="@nameof(BidViewModel.Id)"
                                       ValueField="@nameof(BidViewModel.Id)"
                                       Width="100%" PopupWidth="170px" AllowCustom="true" Class="form-control"
                                       Filterable="true" FilterOperator="StringFilterOperator.Contains"
                                       OnChange="@((object selectedId) => BidSelected(_claimItem, selectedId))">
                      </TelerikComboBox>
                   }
                </EditorTemplate>
             </GridColumn>
             <GridColumn Field=@nameof(BQM.Data.Models.Claim_Item.ItemId)>
                <EditorTemplate Context="EditItem">
                   @{
                      var _claimItem = EditItem as Data.Models.Claim_Item;
                      <TelerikComboBox @bind-Value="@_claimItem.ItemId" Data="@_items"
                                       TextField="@nameof(BQM.Data.Models.Bid_Item.ItemId)"
                                       ValueField="@nameof(BQM.Data.Models.Bid_Item.ItemId)"
                                       Width="100%" PopupWidth="170px" AllowCustom="true" Class="form-control"
                                       Filterable="true" FilterOperator="StringFilterOperator.Contains"
                                       OnChange="@((object selectedId) => BidItemSelected(_claimItem, selectedId))">
                      </TelerikComboBox>
                   }
                </EditorTemplate>
             </GridColumn>
             <GridColumn Field=@nameof(BQM.Data.Models.Claim_Item.CustomerItemId)>
                <EditorTemplate Context="EditItem">
                   @{
                      var _claimItem = EditItem as Data.Models.Claim_Item;
                      <TelerikAutoComplete Data="@_xrefItems" @bind-Value="@_claimItem.CustomerItemId"
                                           Width="100%" PopupWidth="50%" Class="form-control"
                                           Filterable="true" FilterOperator="StringFilterOperator.Contains"
                                           OnChange="@((object selectedId) => UpdateLineItem(_claimItem, selectedId))"
                                           OnRead="@ReadItems" ValueField="@nameof(BQM.Data.Models.Item.Id)">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                            @context.ItemDescription
                         </ItemTemplate>
                      </TelerikAutoComplete>
                   }
                </EditorTemplate>
             </GridColumn>
             <GridColumn Field=@nameof(BQM.Data.Models.Claim_Item.Quantity) />
             <GridColumn Field=@nameof(BQM.Data.Models.Claim_Item.SalePrice) DisplayFormat="{0:C2}" />
             <GridColumn Field=@nameof(BQM.Data.Models.Claim_Item.BidPrice) DisplayFormat="{0:C2}" />
             <GridColumn Field="Claim_Reason.Description" Title="Reason" Editable="false">
                <Template>
                   @((context as BQM.Data.Models.Claim_Item).Claim_Reason.Description)
                </Template>
             </GridColumn>
             <GridColumn Field=@nameof(BQM.Data.Models.Claim_Item.DateProofOfSale) DisplayFormat="{0:d}" Editable="true" />
             <GridColumn Field=@nameof(BQM.Data.Models.Claim_Item.DateModified) />
             <GridColumn Field=@nameof(BQM.Data.Models.Claim_Item.ModifiedBy) />
             <GridCommandColumn Width="200px">
                <BSButtonGroup>
                   <AuthorizeView Policy="@Policies.ClaimRebateItemCreateEdit" Context="Edit">
                      <EditButton linkText="Edit" />
                      <GridCommandButton Command="Save" Icon="save" ShowInEdit="true">Save</GridCommandButton>
                      <CancelButton linkText="Cancel" />
                   </AuthorizeView>
                   <AuthorizeView Policy="@Policies.ClaimRebateItemDelete" Context="Edit">
                      <DeleteButton linkText="Delete" />
                   </AuthorizeView>
                </BSButtonGroup>
             </GridCommandColumn>
          </GridColumns>
       </TelerikGrid>
```

Comment: This is usually when you create a new element without initializing the fields and yet you try to access a property or method from those uninitialized fields. You have one possible case in your code: `Claim_Item.Claim_Reason.Description`. Did you initialized `Claim_Reason` in the constructor?

Comment: You are brilliant!! I have been pulling my hair out on this. I actually thought the issue was further up in the code on the EditContext. While this may not completely resolve the issue. Now, I am no longer receiving the nullexception. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine how did you know that the issue was with Claim_Item.Claim_Reason.Description?

Comment: You were adding in the Grid a newly created item `Claim_Item`. I just looked for parts in your code where you tried to access a property/method of a property of `Claim_Item`. This was the only one I saw.